# Multiple sites using the same domain with each site in a subfolder

Tags: aegir

I am looking to migrate our multisite Drupal install to AEGIR but what I can not find clarity on is setting up domains for each site. Our current multi-site structure sets up independent Drupal sites under a sub folder of the same domain. We would like to replicate this under AEGIR however it seems each site is unique & requires it's own personal domain and can not share the same domain the way we currently have it.

TL;DR
Is it possible to use the same domain and setup multiple AEGIR sites up as a sub folder under the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need the 'Site subdirectories' module which is included in the main Aegir distribution.

You can find it on `admin/hosting` under the Experimental category.

Comment: Everything seems to be working as expected however even after re-verifying the parent site every sub site created still shows the re-verify warning. I understand this is a module from the experimental section but do you know if this is normal behavior?